# Rails XML :include

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

Here are my models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to    :picture,               :foreign_key  => 'picture_id', 
                                        :class_name   => 'UploadedFile', 
                                        :dependent    => :destroy

  has_many      :enrolled_groups,      :through      => :interests
  ...
end


class Group < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :enrolled_users,       :through      => :interests,
                                  :source       => :user
end
```

I want to get an XML feed for my Groups with the enrolled users and their picture information.

The following line works fine (just with the enrolled users):

```
render :xml => @group.to_xml(:include => [:enrolled_users] )
```

How can I also include the picture info in the feed? I tried a bunch of things but can't figure it out... any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get it to work with the other proposed solutions. The way I ended up doing it was as follow:

In the controller:

```
render :xml => @group.to_xml(:include => {:enrolled_users => {:methods => :picture_url}})
```

In the model:

```
def picture_url
    HOST+picture.public_filename(:avatar)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If doing .to_xml(:include => [:enrolled_users, :picture]) doesn't work, then the hacky way would be to add (in User class):

```
def attributes
  super.merge(:picture => picture)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access nested resources by something like this:

```
render :xml => @group.to_xml(:include => [{:enrolled_users => :picture}])
```